# Automapper: Convert string to datetime from dataset

Tags: c#, automapper, typeconverter

I use automapper to map a dataset to an IEnumerable of an object i created.

I have a dataset that looks like (testcode):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<string, DateTimeOffset>().ConvertUsing<StringToDateTimeOffsetConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing<StringToDateTimeConverter>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, SentMessageListItem>()
              .ForMember(dest => dest.SentDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(2)))
              .ForMember(dest => dest.DeleteDate, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetString(3)));

        var sentmessages = Mapper.Map<IDataReader, IEnumerable<SentMessageListItem>>(Model.DataSet.CreateDataReader());
    }
}

public class SentMessageListItem
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Subject { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTimeOffset SentDate { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime DeleteDate { get; set; }
}

internal class StringToDateTimeOffsetConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTimeOffset>
{
    public DateTimeOffset Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var objDateTime = context.SourceValue;
        DateTimeOffset dateTime;

        if (objDateTime == null)
        {
            return default(DateTimeOffset);
        }

        if (DateTimeOffset.TryParse(objDateTime.ToString(), out dateTime))
        {
            return dateTime;
        }

        return default(DateTimeOffset);
    }
}

internal class StringToDateTimeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(ResolutionContext context)
    {
        var objDateTime = context.SourceValue;
        DateTime dateTime;

        if (objDateTime == null)
        {
            return default(DateTime);
        }

        if (DateTime.TryParse(objDateTime.ToString(), out dateTime))
        {
            return dateTime;
        }

        return default(DateTime);
    }
}

public static class Model
{
    public static readonly DataSet DataSet = GetDataSet();

    private static DataSet GetDataSet()
    {
        var set = new DataSet();
        var table1 = new DataTable();
        table1.Columns.Add("id");
        table1.Columns.Add("subject");
        table1.Columns.Add("sentdate");
        table1.Columns.Add("deletedate");
        table1.Rows.Add("0", "Subject", "01/01/2013", "01/01/2013");
        set.Tables.Add(table1);

        return set;
    }
}
```

error:

```
Mapping types:
IDataReader -> IEnumerable`1
System.Data.IDataReader -> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[CNH.CSCN.BBS.Entities.Domain.Entities.SentMessageListItem, CNH.CSCN.BBS.Entities, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]

Destination path:
IEnumerable`1

Source value:
System.Data.DataTableReader
```

What am i doing wrong?

The error is caused by the datetimeoffset and datetime, because if i remove them, automapper has no problem with mapping my dataset to my object.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when mapping is not properly registered and trying to use it. If the Source and Destination object properties are different please use the below logic to map.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<IDataReader, SentMessageListItem>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.A, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.A))   // A -> A Optional (Both 'A' are same)
    .ForMember(dest => dest.B, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BB))  // BB -> B
```

Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348812/how-to-use-automapper-to-create-complex-viewmodel-objects-from-a-simple-object-a/13355873#13355873) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13407044/automapper-doesnt-map-calculated-field-to-scalar/13409228#13409228)

Comment: I have adjusted my code, but the error still appears and my converter class is still not used.(update visible in my original post)

Comment: @Selketjah, Can u please post the complete sample code in Console Application. It is just confusing for me.

Comment: @Selketjah, No. What is IDataReader ?

Comment: An interface from .NET itself: System.Data.IDataReader

Comment: @Selketjah, It is not possible to map. You can map from one Class to another class (object tot object mapping).

Comment: Yes, I have mapped from an IDataReader many times before without any problems, but this is the first time i have a datetime in my object class and I don't know how to make automapper map it.